# When are placed next to each other VS When they are placed next to each other

Tags: relative-clauses

**There is no difference between the two dogs when are placed next to each other.**

**There is no difference between the two dogs when they are placed next to each other.**

Which one do you think is correct?

Comment: The second one ("...when they are placed...") is correct; the first one is not.

Comment: It would be possible to say 'when placed next to each other', but if you use 'are' you must also include 'they'.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you Kate. Really helpful to know that. I always thought that using passive voice always required a to be verb